# Get https://abcd.azure.io/v2/: dial tcp: lookup abcd.azure.io on 192.168.65.1:53: no such host

Tags: docker, acr

I am not able to push docker image to azure container registry. It is giving the below error:
Get https://abcd.azure.io/v2/: dial tcp: lookup abcd.azure.io on 192.168.65.1:53: no such host

Tried below options but no luck:

1. restarted docker
2. turned off VPN
3. disconnected and connected wifi
4. enables google DNS (8.8.8.8)

Can anyone help me here what else could be done.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the command line tools "dig" (Linux or Mac) or "nslookup" (Windows) to verify DNS settings.